Process not showing in Process Explorer, even though it's running
Something strange is happening, I am running the game "Sheep dog 'n' wolf" via the SheepD3D.exe executable.
While it is running I alt-tab and open SysInternals' Process Explorer (latest version). The executable is nowhere to be found. Filtering by its name yields no results. I can't drag the "find window's process" crosshair over it, since it's so old it can only run in full screen.
However, when I open Process Hacker, the executable is plainly visible there:

controversly:

Why ProcExp can't see the exe?

Is the old SheepD3D.exe running in some Windows Application compatibility mode? Windows 10 show all application compatibility settings in effect for running program has a suggestion to use Process Hacker to look at the value of the __COMPAT_LAYER environment variable. That might help understand why Process Explorer doesn't detect the old program. Understanding Shims might help in explaining how Windows Application compatibility mode works.

@ChesterGillon, I've yet to read about shims, but, yes, the __COMPAT_LAYER env var has a value of DWM8And16BitMitigation for that application. I take it ProcExp can't see processes with that compatability?

I am able to see SheepD3D.exe in Process Explorer 17.5 on Windows 11 23H2 using the same Sheep filter.
Ideas

Maybe SheepD3D.exe is running as a different user than Process Explorer is, and View > Show Processes From All Users is disabled?
Process Explorer might be paused, giving you an outdated view of running processes. If so, the status bar will show "Paused". Press Space to toggle.



Thank you for procuring a copy of the program to test! Show Processes From All Users is enabled and ProcExp is not paused. Does yours run in a compatibility mode?

The only compatibility mode I use for Process Explorer is "Run this program as an administrator," purely for convenience. SHEEPD3D's __COMPAT_LAYER env var is the same DWM8And16BitMitigation value you saw, I didn't see or enable any others.
